# How to bind React state to RxJS observable stream?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

can someone help me how to bind React State to RxJS Observable? I did sth like

```
componentDidMount() {
  let source = Rx.Observable.of(this.state.val)
}
```

The ideal result is, whenever `this.state.val` updated (via `this.setState(...)`) `source` get updated too, so I can combine `source` with other RxJS observable stream.

However, in this case, `source` only get updated once, even after `this.state.val` is updated and component is re-rendered.

```
// Ideal result:
this.state.val = 1
source.subscribe(val => console.log(x)) //=> 1
this.state.val = 2
source.subscribe(val => console.log(val)) //=> 2

// Real result:
this.state.val = 1
source.subscribe(val => console.log(x)) //=> 1
this.state.val = 2
source.subscribe(val => console.log(val)) //=> 1 ???WTH
```

It might be because `componentDidMount()` only invoked once in React lifetime. so I move `source` to `componentDidUpdate()` which is invoked everytime after component is rendered. However, the result still remain the same.

**So the question is how to make `source` updated whenever `this.state.val` updated?**

**Updated:** Here is the solution I used to solve the prob, using `Rx.Subject`

```
// Component file
constructor() {
  super(props)
  this.source = new Rx.Subject()
_onChangeHandler(e) {
 this.source.onNext(e.target.value)
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.source.subscribe(x => console.log(x)) // x is updated
}
render() {
  <input type='text' onChange={this._onChangeHandler} />
}
//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to use `Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges` > cf. `https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/ofobjectchanges.md`.

However :

- It uses `Object.observe` which is not a standard feature, hence will have to be polyfilled in some browsers and is actually being removed from inclusion in ecmascript (cf. http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/object-observe-withdrawn). Not the choice for the future, but it is easy to use, so if it is just for your own needs, why not.

Other option is to use a subject in one of the three methods at your disposal according to your use case : `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate`. Cf. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html for when each function is executed. In one of these methods, you would check if `this.state.val` has changed, and emits its new value on the subject if it did.

I am not a `reactjs` specialist, so I guess they might be other options.

Comment: Thank you, I did managed to get it worked by using `Rx.Subject` before your answer with a little different approach. But I will mark your answer is correct any way because it is right answer and it is interesting to know there is `Rx.Observable.ofObjectChanges`. Sad to know `Object.observe` is withdrawn.

Comment: I am glad. You should consider sharing your approach here for future viewers with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

To abstract out some of the below complexity, use recompose's [mapPropsStream](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mappropsstream) or [componentFromStream](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mappropsstream).  E.g.

```
const WithMouseMove = mapPropsStream((props$) => {
  const { handler: mouseMove, stream: mouseMove$ } = createEventHandler();

  const mousePosition$ = mouseMove$
    .startWith({ x: 0, y: 0 })
    .throttleTime(200)
    .map(e => ({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }));

  return props$
    .map(props => ({ ...props, mouseMove }))
    .combineLatest(mousePosition$, (props, mousePosition) => ({ ...props, ...mousePosition }));
});

const DumbComponent = ({ x, y, mouseMove }) => (
  <div
    onMouseMove={mouseMove}
  >
    <span>{x}, {y}</span>
  </div>
);

const DumbComponentWithMouseMove = WithMouseMove(DumbComponent);
```

### Original Post

For a slightly updated answer to the OP's updated answer, using rxjs5, I came up with the following:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mouseMove$ = new Rx.Subject();
    this.mouseMove$.next = this.mouseMove$.next.bind(this.mouseMove$);

    this.mouseMove$
      .throttleTime(1000)
      .subscribe(idx => {
        console.log('throttled mouse move');
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mouseMove$.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
       onMouseMove={this.mouseMove$.next}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Some notable additions:

- `onNext()` is now `next()`
- binding the observable `next` method allows it to be passed directly to the mouseMove handler
- streams should be unsubscribed in `componentWillUnmount` hook

Furthermore, the subject streams initialized in the component `constructor` hook can be passed as properties to 1+ child component(s), which could all push to the stream using any of the observable next/error/complete methods.  [Here's a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/woxowehase/edit?js,output) I put together demonstrating multiple event streams shared between multiple components.

Curious if anyone has ideas on how to better encapsulate this logic to simplify stuff like binding and unsubscribing.

Answer (score 1):

Although a subject will work, I think the [best practice](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93) is to avoid using a subject when you can use an observable.  In this case you can use `Observable.fromEvent`:

```js
class MouseOverComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mouseMove$ = Rx.Observable
      .fromEvent(this.mouseDiv, "mousemove")
      .throttleTime(1000)
      .subscribe(() => console.log("throttled mouse move"));

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mouseMove$.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(ref) => this.mouseDiv = ref}>
          Move the mouse...
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<MouseOverComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here it is on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mikebridge/pen/XgeMwK/)....

It seems to me that there are other times when a Subject like the best choice, like when a custom React component executes a function when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading this blog post on streaming props to a React component using RxJS:

https://medium.com/@fahad19/using-rxjs-with-react-js-part-2-streaming-props-to-component-c7792bc1f40f

It uses [FrintJS](https://frint.js.org), and applies the `observe` higher-order component for returning the props as a stream:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { observe } from 'frint-react';

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <p>Interval: {props.interval}</p>;
}

export default observe(function () {
  // return an Observable emitting a props-compatible object here
  return Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(x => ({ interval: x }));
})(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using hooks.

Here is a code [sample](https://github.com/bnayae/react-rx-playground)

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useObservable<T = number | undefined>(
    observable: Observable<T | undefined>,
    initialState?: T): T | undefined {
    const [state, setState] = useState<T | undefined>(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription: Subscription = observable.subscribe(
            (next: T | undefined) => {
                setState(next);
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => setState(undefined));
        return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }, [observable])

    return state;
}
```